# What are the DDR5 recommended CL?

Tags: memory

I'm in search of a new memory for my laptop upgrade. The laptop runs i7-12700H, so I'm bound to the 4800 Mt/s memory. As my previous laptop was 11th gen i7, I'm kinda not used to the DDR5 memory and trying to figure out what should be the timings for the new memory.

I'm checking for example these sticks from Teamgroup and I see they list CL40
[TEAMGROUP Elite SODIMM DDR5 32GB (2x16GB) 4800MHz (PC5-38400) CL40 Non-ECC Unbuffered 1.1V 262 Pin Laptop Memory Module Ram - TED532G4800C40DDC-S01](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09X1ZHP62)

On the other sticks from other vendors I see CL36, but not sure this is the best value too.

What are the best DDR5 RAM CL timings available on the market?

Answer (score 1):

When talking about RAM speeds, more MHz and lower CL is faster. 4800MHz is the lowest DDR5 can go, and if you try to go higher with faster sticks, it defaults to 4800Mhz CL40. For example, if you put in a 5600MHz CL40 stick (like the Kingston Fury Impact) and your laptop doesn't support it, it will slow down the stick. 4800MHz CL40 seems to be kinda normal for DDR5 SODIMM (from a quick Tweakers Pricewatch search) and it isn't terrible, but I think that in a few years we will look at that and think it's slow for DDR5

Comment: thanks for the response. I don't care what happens in a few years, by my experinece I always change laptop and memory together, so next upgrade I likely will buy smth more up to date. Speaking about 12700H and [ADL-P PCH chipset](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/platforms/details/alder-lake-p.html), will I achieve significant gain if I buy CL36/32 instead of CL40?

Comment: I really don't know either, DDR5 is kinda new for me too. I would think no, only slight gains but it's prob app dependant